# Use a "months" array to perform calculations for each month in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, meteor-helper

I have a mongo collection to store "projects", each document stores a project with different calculations for each month of the year

```
a_jan : 10,
a_feb : 20,
a_mar : 25,
a_apr : 70
...

b_jan : 30,
b_feb : 10,
b_mar : 20,
b_apr : 70
...

c_jan : 80,
c_feb : 2,
c_mar : 20,
c_apr : 65
...
```

I've created a template helper to perform some maths calculations, involving fields for each month (i.e. : `rtwc_jan = (a_jan + b_jan) / c_jan`).

There are a lot of different calculations, but same calculation is performed for each month.

How can I use a `for` loop to accommodate the array `key` coming from a "months" array?

This is my code (w/o the for loop...)

```
var months = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","des"];

var arrayLength = months.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        alert(months[i]);       

        // Need to Calculate rtcw for each month        

        var scope = {
                a_jan : currentProject.a_jan,
                b_jan : currentProject.b_jan,
                c_jan : currentProject.c_jan,
        };      

        var calculation_a = math.eval('(a_jan - b_jan) * c_jan / 35', scope);

        scope.a = calculation_a;

        var rtcw_jan = math.eval('max(a,15)', scope);

        console.log(rtcw_jan);
}
```

Comment: What are you using Mathjs for?

Comment: These are not actual calculations, for simplicity I copied this code here. We  use some engineering calculations and plan to include more complex ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get the properties from your currentProject object by using the month as a key.  Like this:

```
var months = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","des"];
var arrayLength = months.length;
var rtcw = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        alert(months[i]);

        // Need to Calculate rtcw for each month
        var scope = {
                a : currentProject["a_" + months[i]],
                b : currentProject["b_" + months[i]],
                c : currentProject["c_" + months[i]],
        };

        var calculation_a = math.eval('(a - b) * c / 35', scope);

        scope.a = calculation_a;

        rtcw[months[i]] = math.eval('max(a,15)', scope);
        console.log(rtcw[months[i]]);
}
```

Simplified:

```
var months = ["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","des"];
var rtcw = {};

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) 
{
    var a = currentProject["a_" + months[i]];
    var b = currentProject["b_" + months[i]];
    var c = currentProject["c_" + months[i]];

    rtcw[months[i]] = max((a - b) * c / 35, 15);

    console.log(rtcw[months[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Right @PhillTreddenick!, and how to use `months[i]` as part of a `var` name? `var rtcw_jan` should iterate over months also. (I am learning javascript, sorry if this trivial...)

Comment: Probably you want something like this:`var rtcw = {};
            rtcw[months[i]] = math.eval('max(a,15)', scope);
            console.log(rtcw[months[i]]);`

Comment: Exactly that, marked as correct answer. Thanks Phill!